# Why did I have to remove bin/sh to run the winpty docker run command?

Tags: docker, git-bash, winpty

I am running a simple docker image and want to check if the applications have been installed. As I am running on windows I need to run the infamous winpty.

I noticed, however, through trial and error. That the below does not work

`winpty docker run --r hpjn/doc-training:1.0/bin/sh`

However, if I run:

`winpty docker run --r hpjn/doc-training:1.0/`
I can enter winpty and perform my checks.

A simple question is why did I have to remove /bin/sh?

Cheers

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what happens?  Is there a space between the image name `hpjn/doc-training:1.0` and the command `/bin/sh`?  What's actually in the image?